# ASP MVC Friendly URL's and Relative Path Images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, relative-path

I have an ASP.NET MVC page, where I am trying to show friendly URL's.

So, I have a Category View in the Home Controller, that accepts a categoryKey value to get the content of the page.

For instance: http://localhost/Home/Category/Bikes gets the bike content.

in my Global.asax.cs, i have the following to handle this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
      "Category",
      "{controller}/{action}/{categoryKey}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Category", categoryKey = "" });

  routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
}
```

This works just fine, and it gets the content, however, I am getting the content from a Content Management system, for easy editing.  When you add an image on the content management, it adds the image with a relative path:

```
<img src="../AdminUploadContent/bikes.gif" alt="Bikes" />
```

Now, if i goto "http://localhost/Home/Category", and that image tag is on the base page, it will pull up the image.  However, if i goto "http://localhost/Home/Category/", or add the actual category of "/Home/Category/Bikes"/, the image doesn't show up.  The properties of the image is pointing to "http://localhost/Home/AdminUploadContent/bikes.gif".

Is there anything I can put in my Global.aspx.cs file to handle the relative path?  Even if i manually edit the content management to add ../../AdminUploadContent/bikes.gif, it is chopping off the first ../, since it is doing some validation.

Answer (score 47):

Use the [Url.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) method when generating a path to your image.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/AdminUploadContent/bikes.gif")" />
```

or if using the WebForms view engine:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/AdminUploadContent/bikes.gif") %>" />
```

Comment: runat="server" is not needed in this case i think

Comment: @marcind, hi, i am saving Imagepath in database as : `c://user/tom/images` ,  i am not able to retrieve it in view, why ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the relative path " ~/ " to refer to the current virtual directory where the page is located. Try to add runat="server" attribute to your "img" tag and "~" sign in "src" attribute:

```
<img runat="server" src="~/AdminUploadContent/bikes.gif" alt="Bikes" />
```

Comment: I would not recommend mixing the asp.net Webforms idiom with asp.net mvc.  Stick to this    <pre><img src="@Url.Content("~/AdminUploadContent/bikes.gif")" alt="Bikes" /></pre>

Answer (score 1):

This works too.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/yourimage.png")"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom http module that will rewrite path from the relative ../../img.png to needed handling the Referer http header, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had to just Add / to the src attribute

Before:

```
<div><img alt='' src='" & image_url & "' style='vertical-align: top; height: 40px'/><div class='auto-style1' style='padding: 10px'></div>
```

After:

```
<div><img alt='' src='/" & image_url & "' style='vertical-align: top; height: 40px'/><div class='auto-style1' style='padding: 10px'></div>
```

Where image_url is a Function of my page code-behind class.